# Насколько оправдано использование слова "оперативно"?

Tags: значение-слова

Добрый день всем. В связи с прошедшим профессиональным праздником хочу задать давно интересующий меня и моих коллег вопрос. Сейчас повсеместно, к месту и не к месту употребляется слово "оперативно". Мы оперативно сообщим, оперативно привезем, оперативно узнаем. Это режет ухо людям, которые действительно имеют дело с оперативной работой. Потому что сообщить, привезти, узнать оперативно - это значит с задействованием оперативных средств и методов. Что есть нелепица в области торговли, услуг и тому подобное. Не стоило бы вернуть это слово в те сферы, где оно имеет прямой смысл, а именно в медицину, военное дело и специальные службы? Потому что слово "оперативно" не пустышка, а относится к той области, где есть "операция". Да и опошливание некоторое слова происходит. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, очень любопытна ваша точки зрения, так сказать, гражданскими глазами. Я посмотрел словарь Кузнецова. Но дело в том, что и в ответе уважаемой дамы и в словаре, который 2000 года, уже наблюдается аберрация первозданного,так сказать, значения. Дело в том, что я застал время, когда "оперативный" употреблялось только в первом и втором значении статьи г-на Кузнецова. Третьего значения просто не было, по крайней мере, это мог быть жаргон и то строго непрофессиональный. Дело в том, что существуют ещё словари оперативной лексики, если у вас есть ссылки, то это могло бы нам помочь разобраться.

Comment: Так вот, они составлены в 70-80 годы. Там есть точное разграничение между "операцией" и "действиями". Поэтому называть операциями простые действия, категорически нельзя. Наоборот операция состоит из отдельных действий. Сходить, посмотреть, поговорить - это действия. И в силу смазывания исконного значения с ныне модным происходят такие ляпы. Извините, например, у дамы - оперативно узнал означает, что узнал строго по оперативным (агентурным каналам), именно в отличие от сходил, посмотрел, поговорил. В словаре пример: "судить по оперативным данным."- вот такие фразы и вызвали мой вопрос.

Comment: Тут категорическая ошибка. Кузнецов дальше поясняет: "по последним поступившим сведениям". Нет же, "по оперативным данным" - это строго по Оперативным (агентурным и др. специальным) данным, в отличие от просто по "последним поступившим" (слухам). Я просто хотел акцентировать, что пренебрежение в последнее время словами особенно в СМИ и уже в речи простых обывателей доводит до искажения смысла. А это может быть очень существенным, когда ситуация требует серьезного и ответственного подхода. Я думал, может, филологи придают этому значение и могут повлиять на моду говорить бессмысленно. Спасибо.

Comment: >> Дело в том, что я застал время, когда "оперативный" употреблялось только в первом и втором значении статьи г-на Кузнецова. Третьего значения просто не было, по крайней мере, это мог быть жаргон и то строго непрофессиональный.

Ну уж... Фильм "Служебный роман" когда снимался? Там Самохвалов, герой Басилашвили, произносит: "Вот спасибо, оперативно!" — имея в виду, что ему быстро отремонтировали кабинет.

Не понимаю, почему вы так недовольны. Ну, постепенно развилось такое значение у слова — оно что, путает оперативников? И директивами тут ничего не сделаешь: говорят – значит, говорят.

Comment: Ну да Вы правы. Было там такое. Ну я же не говорю, что вообще не говорили. Да, был жаргон. Но, как я понимаю, на то и жаргон, чтобы быть на улице. А в СМИ использовать жаргон? Не знаю. Есть же язык БиБиСи. А оперативников не путает, только смешит.Звучи нелепо. В советские годы пресса придавала значение слову. Если в нынешние Вы считаете это не обязательно? Хорошо, просто мы придем к тому, что каждый будет вкладывать свой смысл, говорить неграмотно. Если вы филологи на это смотрите спокойно, тогда у меня больше вопросов нет. А директивами, как и "пушками", очень даже сделаешь. История показала

Comment: Это не жаргон. Просто слово из профессиональной лексики перешло в общую. И перешло-то именно в советские годы, не в нынешние.

**ЖАРГОН, -а; м. [франц. jargon]
Речь какой-л. социальной или профессиональной группы, содержащая большое количество свойственных только этой группе слов и выражений (часто искусственных, тайных или условных)**

А как директивами-то? В тюрьму сажать, штрафами душить? )))) Филологи этим не занимаются.

Comment: @Archimedes, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исключить  медицинскую терминологию, то у слова «операция»  можно выделить два значения:

(1) ряд действий, объединенных одной целью (военная или правоохранительная операция,  производные слова: оперативная сводка, оперативный штаб, оперативник);

(2) отдельное действие (банковская операция, производные слова: операционный зал в банке, оператор).

Оперативный и операционный – относительные прилагательные, но в современном языке слово «оперативный»  стало употребляться  и **в качественном значении (об этом говорит наличие краткой формы).** Оперативный –  это действующий быстро, профессионально, умеющий исправить и направить действие в нужном направлении, то есть действующий так же, как при проведении ответственной операции. Это качественное значение получает дальнейшее развитие, и оперативным теперь называют  своевременное и грамотное решение, даже если оно будет включать только одно действие.

Но нужно ли нам  слово с таким расширенным значением?  Наверное, да, потому что оно обозначает определенное понятие.  Ведь оперативное исполнение – это не только быстрое решение проблемы, но и решение с гарантией  даже в тех случаях, когда могут возникнуть какие-либо непредвиденные  обстоятельства.  Об оперативности уместно говорить тогда, когда решаемая задача нестандартна или может зависеть от различных факторов  в меняющемся окружении.

Но конечно, следует сказать о культуре пользования  словом «оперативно», а она оставляет желать лучшего.  Нельзя абсолютно всё делать оперативно, по уместности употребления этого слова можно судить о языковой культуре человека.

Comment: Блестящий ответ. Именно такими я филологов себе и представлял. Маленькая ремарка - последний абзац и есть, собственно, ответ на мой вопрос. Про неуместность.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Слово, конечно, не пустышка, Вы правы,  в названных выражениях (оперативно сообщим, оперативно привезем, оперативно узнаем) употребляется оно несколько неправомерно, потому что значение "действующий быстро и своевременно" предполагает всё-таки какие-то действия, связанные с отдельными операциями: оперативно решим вопрос-верно, "решим в несколько действий", а оперативно сообщим-некорректно, там значение просто "Быстро, без проволочек", оперативно привезём - тоже, а вот оперативно узнал что-то - возможно, если для того, чтобы узнать, нужно совершить много операций: сходить туда-то, посмотреть там-то, поговорить с тем-то.

Таким образом, оперативно, т.е. быстро, можно употреблять в значении "быстро произвести какие-то действия", а не одно действие. Здесь оперативно связано со значением слова "операция" - отдельное действие в ряду подобных: банковская операция, почтовая операция, отделочная операция.

Comment: Я опиралась на Ожегова: 
http://xn----8sbauh0beb7ai9bh.xn--p1ai/%D0%BE%D0%
http://xn----8sbauh0beb7ai9bh.xn--p1ai/%D0%BE%D0
Новые значения будут появляться, хотим мы этого или нет, а значение слова операция " отдельное действие в ряду других подобных 
Пример: Банковая о. Почтовая о. Отделочная о. Машинная о." имеется и зафиксировано у Ожегова и в ряде других словарей. Придётся с этим смириться

Comment: Я Вам благодарен за ответ. Вы меня им натолкнули на мысль. Оперативный обесценивается, потому что обесценивается слово "операция". Теперь просто действие называется операцией. Далее, если продолжим цепочку - настоящая операция нынче в СМИ называется исключительно "спецоперация", что тоже смешно для специалиста. Спецоперация это тоже не пустой звук, а означает совершенно конкретные вещи, в частности, там должно быть то, для чего добавляется "спец". Но это детали. Кстати, не исключено, что в этом же ряду на каждом шагу звучит - спец, супер, ультра, мега? Говорить просто нынче не модно?

Comment: Это Вы у нас спрашиваете? На эту тему дискуссий предостаточно. Выход один: пусть каждый следит за своей речью, по возможности избегая иностранных слов,и учит этому своих детей. Дети, к сожалению, быстрее воспринимают иностранную лексику, чем пытаются понять свою исконную. И учителя ничего не сделают, их учит общение, а общение чаще всего в интернете, там русский язык не в приоритете.

Comment: И слово операция в значении "действие" закреплено в цифровой технике,особенно в виде неологизма "опция". Я вот поначалу в телефоне никак не могла освоить его значение, а дети в один момент поняли без всяких словарей.

Comment: Людмила, но "опция" — это не "действие". Опции — это параметры настройки компьютерной программы, если не заглядывать в словари. Или "режимы работы программы". Могу установить эту опцию, могу не устанавливать.

Comment: Да, но я с этим словом познакомилась на своём телефоне. кнопка "опции" там означала "меню", т.е. выбор функций, а функции - это и есть действия, синоним -"операция". Разве не так? И эти действия перечислены:отправить сообщение,внести в контакты, удалить и т.д.Это же не режим программы, а именно функции-операции-действия? Или нет?

Comment: Людмила, не знаю, как перевели в телефоне, хотя это странный авторитет, Вы разве не помните китайские переводы инструкций их товаров, но "опция" - это вариант, выбор. Кстати, если происходит аберрация значения уже привычных, русский слов, как мы выяснили, то что говорить про недавно заимствованные, значение оригинала почти никто не знает.

Comment: Вы хорошо написали про культуру и правильность речи, про иностранную лексику, про воспитание детей. В русле этой темы и отвечая на реплики молодого человека выше, просто вспомнилось, что, например, наши демократичные европейские партнеры уже решили эту проблему. Многое на самом деле они привыкли решать именно директивно. Кстати, штрафы у них на порядки больше наших. Применяют их весьма щедро. Нам и не снилось. Все, что касается общественной безопасности и даже культурной самобытности в самом широком смысле, в Европе регулируется крайне жестко. Да и не только в Европе. А "путь каждый" - это, к

Comment: это, к сожалению, на выходе означает, что никто нигде и никогда. Справедливости ради надо сказать, что В Европе присутствует достаточно высокий уровень сознательности и внутренней культуры. Но это результат многовекового воспитания огнем и железом. И даже при этом, при этой общей высокой культуре, репрессивные меры государства гораздо жестче наших. Просто они точечные и неотвратимые, поэтому мы их как бы не замечаем. Но они есть. И вопросы культуры, например, количество иностранной, в основном англоязычной, музыки и фильмов ограничено законом. Это у нас представить сложно. Ну и другие меры.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, слово вошло в моду, это правда. Но одно из значений слова "оперативный", от которого и произошло наречие "оперативно" — это "действующий быстро и своевременно, умело направляющий ход дела при изменяющихся обстоятельствах" (Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова).

Comment: одно из значений слова "оперативный", от которого и произошло наречие "оперативно".. Слово ОперативнО НЕ произошло от слова ОперативныЙ. И более того, слово записанное, или акцентированное иначе - оперАтивный  имеет иное смысловое значение.

Answer (score 1):

Archimedes, совершенно не понял смысл ваших призывов. 
"Задвинуть назад" слово, которое приобрело (пусть даже и в результате неверного понимания) какое-то новое значение, ну уж никак не получится.

Но я даже не об этом. 
Вы можете четко сказать, какое именно из значений (ну хотя бы по Кузнецову) - неправильно?

> Мы оперативно сообщим,

Что здесь не так? даже с позиций "опера"? Не "быстро", а "как только станет известно", "как только сможем".

> оперативно привезем,

Ну тут скорее да. Хотя тоже нельзя "рубить сплеча", может быть и нормально. Вопрос контекста.

> оперативно узнаем

Это ни малейших возражений не вызывает.

Теперь по Кузнецову. 
*===

ОПЕРАТИВНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -вен, -вна, -вно.
1. только полн.
к Операция (1-2 зн.). Предпринять оперативную вылазку. О-ое вмешательство
(хирургическая операция).
2.
Связанный с операциями по задержанию правонарушителей, с расследованием происшествий и преступлений. О-ая работа. О. отдел. О-ое расследование. О-ая группа захвата. О-ые органы
(органы милиции и т.п.). О-ая сводка
(о происшествиях и преступлениях за сутки).
3.
Действующий быстро и своевременно, умело направляющий ход дела при изменяющихся обстоятельствах. О. отклик газеты на события. Составить о-ые планы на декаду. Дать о-ые указания в цеха. Судить по оперативным данным
(по последним поступившим сведениям). О-ая память компьютера
(запоминающее устройство компьютера, используемое непосредственно при выполнении логических и арифметических операций). < Оперативно, нареч. (3 зн.). О. решать вопросы. Оперативность, -и; ж. (3 зн.). О. в работе. О. руководства.*

===
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EE%EF%E5%F0%E0%F2%E8%E2%ED%FB%E9

Знаете, я к Кузнецову отношусь с некоторым скепсисом, но тут мне даже придраться не к чему.
Камень преткновения, как я понял, в третьем значении. Да, оно отлично от первых двух. Не случайно только оно имеет краткую форму. Вот я за это и зацеплюсь. ***"Этот работник - исполнителен и оперативен"***. Что скажете? Запретите как неверное? Если да, то почему? Если нет, то придется признать, что хотя бы одно это значение (как минимум! - но этого тут и достаточно) может быть реализовано и в тех сочетаниях, против которых вы возражаете. А почему нет?

Comment: Простите,я не всё понял. Но попытаюсь сам уточнить свою мысль. Есть определенные правила употребления слов согласно их значениям. Если ребенок или неуважаемый нами человек скажет, например, "этот человек нерентабален". Мы скажем, это не по-русски, надо - нерационален, небережлив и т.д. (Ну или приведите более яркий пример, может сходу этот не самый выпуклый, но мысль, я надеюсь, Вы поняли) Так вот сотрудник оперативен - это речевая ошибка. Также оперативно привезем, оперативно сообщим, оперативно узнаем. Почему, потому что при наличии полудесятка других русских слов: быстро, своевременно,

Comment: скоро, срочно и тд.,(Вы лучше меня знаете синонимический ряд), применять слово, которое имеет другое, совершенно определенное значение - это речевая ошибка. Потому что оперативно привезти - это значит, например, в багажнике под наркозом, оперативно сообщим - это по оперативным средствам связи, оперативно узнаем (я уже писал) - по оперативным каналам. Если для Вас слово "оперативно" уже настолько выцвело, то поясню, оперативные каналы - это агентурные, либо с использованием спецтехники и др. Разве тут нет разницы между просто "быстро",а именно это,всего лишь быстро,имеется в виду на самом деле

Comment: Вы спрашиваете как задвинуть назад. Да очень просто, признать сообществом русистов, что это речевая ошибка, как признано слово "ихний", хотя оно используется 90 процентов населения. Но в СМИ это ошибка и несолидно для приличного человека, тем более недопустимо для журналиста. Вы хотите сказать, что официальный язык должен идти вслед за уличным? Не соглашусь. И подозреваю, что выражаю мнение подавляющего большинства интеллектуального сословия всего мира. Ну может за исключением американцев, но это отдельная тема. Второе, Вы спросили, какое значение словаря неверно. Отвечаю - третье. Это

Comment: Это уже отражение "уличного" значения, жаргонизма, как я сказал выше, хотя, может, это не совсем корректное определение, но не суть, не будем цепляться к словам, давайте обсуждать смыслы и идеи. Хотя, не пойму, почему это не жаргон? Мы же называем жаргоном уличные слова. Ну да, перешел из профессионального в бытовой жаргон. Почему нет?

Comment: **Archimedes**, я вряд ли смогу что-то добавить... Кроме того, что "русисты", как вы их назвали, не занимаются запретительством.

И еще одно. Вы в курсе, что живые языки имеют свойство изменяться? Вот вам и пример изменения в языке. Есть и более яркие примеры, когда слово за 150-200 лет меняет значение чуть ли не на противоположное. Во всяком случае, первоначальное основное значение становится третьим, пятым, да еще с пометой "устар". Пример? Слово "прелестный"."Прелестные письма", скажем. Можно привести сотню примеров, уж поверьте.

Answer (score 0):

Казаться - не значит быть. Извольте относиться к каждой букве как оружию, опасливо - уважительно. Оперативно, операция, оперативные мероприятия, оперативник - не одно и то же. ОперативнО - слово оправдано в ситуациях где присутствует, фактор внезапности.

Comment: Простите, где фактор внезапности в выражении "Он достаточно оперативно решил эту проблему"?-он решил её не внезапно, а быстро и профессионально, с помощью отдельных операций, т. е. практических действий.

Comment: Да нет же, это обывательское наполнение этого слова. Оперативный только от слова операция. Изначально, конечно. Все остальные смыслы - быстрый, внезапный, это уже перенос этого слова на бытовую почву, деривативы. Я просто не понимаю, зачем перемешивать слова, когда у каждого из них есть своё назначение. Оперативный - своё специальное значение, есть слова быстрый, внезапный, срочный, я не знаю, ещё наверняка есть и другие. Почему быстро ответим, быстро привезем уже не нравится народу?

Comment: >> Почему быстро ответим, быстро привезем уже не нравится народу?

Вот это хороший вопрос. От "запретить" вы перешли к "почему".

Во-первых, не всегда "не нравится". Во-вторых, далеко не всему народу. В глубинке, уверен, говорят именно "быстро ответим", "быстро привезем". А не "оперативно".

В-третьих, я не специалист. ))))) Для себя у меня ответ есть, но тут озвучивать не буду.

Comment: Нет, озвучу. )) Мы слышим это "оперативно" в основном в официально-деловой речи, а там оно почти всегда оправданно. А вот если в разговорной — то и правда часто бывает лучше простое "быстро". Люди иногда перебарщивают со стремлением говорить "культурненько".

Comment: Скажите, что филология, настолько делает людей узкомыслящими? Быстро и оперативно не одно и тоже.  Быстро в мегаполисе и быстро в маленьком городке не одно и тоже. Буквы и слова ведь не только справочники. Это информация- которой можно оперировать.

Comment: @Людмила. *проблема* это и есть фактор внезапности, которую решают оперативно.

Comment: Не все проблемы появляются внезапно, есть вечные,их оперативно решить никому не удалось

Comment: Только что перечитывал - вот товарищ спрашивает, что мол делать, штрафовать? Этим филологи не занимаются. Но, позвольте, во Франции, например и в Канадской франкоязычной провинции Квебек занимаются вполне.Я просто не занимался специально этим вопросом,но могу навести справки, по-моему то ли в Ирландии, толи в Исландии та же картина.Если вам интересно, могу специально выяснить мировую, по крайней мере, европейскую практику по тому как филологи или власть в целом директивно регулирует эти процессы.Но в любом случае, неоднократно слышал, как по телевидению поправляли говорящих не местными словам

Comment: Ещё, если позволите, одно уточнение. Тут товарищ спрашивает, точнее, говорит, что не понял смысл моих призывов. Боже упаси, я никого никуда не призываю. Я просто высказал своё наблюдение, постарался, не знаю насколько внятно, выразить свои соображения, не более того. Ваши точки зрения я тоже услышал. Может будут ещё какие-то. Спасибо.